# Swagger's Python SDK returns None despite the API call being successful

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-2.0

This is the code that I have written to make an API call using Swagger Python SDK:

```
import swagger_client
client = swagger_client.ApiClient()
response = client.call_api('/student', 'POST')
print(response)
```

`response` is `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `call_api` method takes the argument `response_type` which can have one of the following values:

- The usual data types that are supported in Python: `int`, `str`, `bool` etc.
- The model corresponding to the object that is returned by the API call: `swagger_client.models.*`

If this argument isn't passed the value returned by `call_api` will be `None`.

In this case:

```
response = client.call_api('/student', 'POST', response_type = swagger_client.models.Student)
```

will return an object of type `Student` and

```
response = client.call_api('/student', 'POST', response_type = 'str')
```

will return a string.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use the `call_api` method of `ApiClient` directly. You can instead use the methods generated in the *Api class (e.g. PetApi):

```
    self.pet_api.add_pet(body=self.pet)

    fetched = self.pet_api.get_pet_by_id(pet_id=self.pet.id)
```

Ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/python/tests/test_pet_api.py#L92